# Can't output a global property in console

Tags: vue.js, console, global

I have a variable stored in a global object, but I can't seem to access it irrespective of what method I use. Here is the code:

```
// Component 
let store = {
  one: [{
    text: 'storage',
    value: '100'
  }],
}

Vue.component('bs-panel', {
  template: '#panel',
  data: function() {
    return {
      count: store,
    }
  },
});

// Initialize Vue
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showPanel: true,
    count: store.one,
  },
  beforeCreate: function() {
    console.log('beforeCreate fired ' + this.count.one.value);
  },
  created: function() {
    console.info('created fired ' + this.count.one.value);
  },
  beforeMount: function() {
    console.log('beforeMount fired ' + this.count.one.value);
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.info('mounted fired: ' + this.count.one.value);
  },
  beforeUpdate: function() {
    console.log('beforeUpdate fired ' + this.count.one.value);
  },
  updated: function() {
    console.info('updated fired ' + this.count.one.value);
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    console.log('beforeDestroy fired ' + this.count.one.value);
  },
  destroyed: function() {
    console.info('destroyed fired ' + this.count.one.value);
  }
})
```

I keep getting a console error.

Here is the Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syed263/z6joyhdL/2/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need mention index of `one` here like `count.one[0].value`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `count : count.one[0].value` to both the components,
and console it correctly, as `one` is an array.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sanketdhoble/z6joyhdL/10/

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the variable only stores an array of value, what if I wanted to access both the value and text? do I need to change the properties again?

Comment: You could make the `store ={ one: {
    text: 'storage',
    value: '100'
  }},`  so you can use `count.one.value` without adding 0 unnecessarily.